# Is changing the state this way direct?

Tags: reactjs

Is this correct?

```
    const {
        flavor, setFlavor,
        cart, setCart
    } = useContext(DataContext);
    
    function addProductToCart(pizza) {
        setCart(cart + 1);
        flavor.push(pizza);
        setFlavor(flavor.filter(item => item));
    }
```

or should i do this?

```
    const {
        flavor, setFlavor,
        cart, setCart
    } = useContext(DataContext);
    
    function addProductToCart(pizza) {
        const copyFlavor = [...flavor];

        setCart(cart + 1);
        copyFlavor.push(pizza);
        setFlavor(copyFlavor.filter(item => item));
    }
```

I know i shouldn't change the state directly, but i don't know if changing like that is directly or not.

Comment: "You shouldn’t change objects that you hold in the React state directly."  [link](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easier and safer way to do it would be.

Although I do not understand the point of the filter you use. *im guessing to generate a new array ?*

```
const {
        flavor, setFlavor,
        cart, setCart
    } = useContext(DataContext);

function addProductToCart(pizza) {
    setCart(cart + 1);
    setFlavor((flavors) => [...flavors, pizza]);
}
```

Comment: i don't know too..., but that's the way i managed to make it work. I tried many other ways and it wasn't working out the way i wanted...